# Using Firebase to retrieve entire object based on 1 attribute?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following Firebase database structure, and I would like to retrieve the entire object that has a host of "Mike 22".

[image]

This is not in a `ValueEventListener` event, so I don't have access to the DataSnapshot. How can I retrieve the object based on that query? I want to do it in an SQL style where you'd type `SELECT object FROM objects WHERE host = "Mike 22"`. Is there any way to do this?

Currently I have the reference to the database as seen below:

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("objects");
```

Answer (score 2):

This is covered in [Sorting and filtering data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data) in the Android Guide. Use `orderByChild` and `equalTo`:

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("objects").orderByChild("host").equalTo("Mike 22");
```

Comment: Okay so after getting that `Query`, what can I do with it? I tried adding a childEventListener but it didn't do anything since I'm not changing the data. I want that query to return an object of the class I created

Comment: @Michael if your query matches any data the child listener will be called once for each existing child and then again for any changes. You can also use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` to read the whole list once.

Comment: Both a `ChildEventListener` and a `ValueEventListener` should trigger when you're attached to the right location and have permission to read the data. To detect the permission, see http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/firebase/5548/how-do-i-listen-for-errors-when-accessing-the-database/22652/detect-errors-when-reading-data-on-android#t=201611302029432848424